# Как датафрейм превратить в вектор

Tags: r

Есть датафрейм

```
  Drugs   Result     Freq
4 drug_1 positive 2.066367
```

Как из него сделать вектор

```
[1] "drug_1"   "positive"
```

Comment: Формально - это `unlist`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Для этого можно воспользоваться функцияей `sapply`.

```r
df <- data.frame(Drugs  = "drug_1", Result = "positive", Freq = 2.066367)
vector <- sapply(df, as.character)

class(vector)
#> [1] "character"

print(vector)
#>      Drugs     Result       Freq 
#>   "drug_1" "positive" "2.066367"
```

<sup>Created on 2019-07-23 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Answer (score 2):

Все гораздо проще.

```
df <- data.frame(Drugs  = "drug_1", Result = "positive", Freq = 2.066367,  
                 stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
as.character(df[, 1:2])
[1] "drug_1"   "positive"
```